# Can't test with the embedded glassfishv3.1.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, glassfish-3

I am studying JavaEE 6 with a book "Beginning JavaEE 6 with Glassfish 3" by Antonio Goncalves. And I faced a problem, I can't deploy my Remote Stateless Java Beans on Glassfish 3+ (glassfish-3.1.2.2), the following snippet represents one:

```
...
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserEJB implements UserEJBRemote {
    public User createUser(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                               IllegalStateException,
                                               PersistenceException {
        ...
    }

public List<User> findAll() throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                   PersistenceException {
    ...
} 

public User findById(Long anId) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return em.find(User.class, anId);
} 

public void removeByMail(String aUserMail) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                                  TransactionRequiredException {

    ...
}

public User update(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                           TransactionRequiredException {

    return em.merge(anUser);                    
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "NotebookUsers")
    private EntityManager em;
}
...
```

My `@Remote` interface declaration is :

```
...
@Remote
public interface UserEJBRemote {
    public User createUser(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                               IllegalStateException,
                                               PersistenceException;
public List<User> findAll() throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                   PersistenceException;

public List<User> findByName(String aUserName) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                                      PersistenceException;

public User findById(Long Id) throws IllegalArgumentException;

public void removeByMail(String aUserMail) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                                  TransactionRequiredException ;

    public User update(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                           IransactionRequiredException ;
}
...
```

Also I have a simple JUnit test, that is failed:

```
public class TestUserEJB {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() throws Exception {
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("target/classes"));
        properties.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.installation.root",
                       "/home/ilya/glassfishv3.1.2/"); 
        ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties); 
        ctx = ec.getContext();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() throws Exception {
        if(null != ec) {
            ec.close();
        }
    }

    @Test 
    public void testCreateAnUser() throws Exception {
        User testUser0 = new User();
        testUser0.setFirstname("Vova");
        testUser0.setSurname("Puchkov");
        testUser0.setMail("vasya.puchkov@gmail.com");
        testUser0.setPhoneNumber("8(777)6769990");

        UserEJB userEJB = (UserEJB) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/UserEJB!" + 
            "beginning.javaee.notebook.UserEJB");           

        userEJB.createUser(testUser0);
        assertNotNull("ID should not be null", testUser0.getId());

        List<User> allUsers = userEJB.findAll();
        assertNotNull("Can't find users", allUsers);        
    }

    private static EJBContainer ec;
    private static Context ctx;
}
```

All the necessary jdbc-data-source and jdbc-connection-pool I created with `glassfish-resources.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool name="jdbc_notebookusers_pool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
pool-resize-quantity="1" max-pool-size="5" steady-pool-size="0"
statement-timeout-in-seconds="60" >
   <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
   <property name="portNumber" value="5432" />
   <property name="dataBaseName" value="javaee-db" />
   <property name="User" value="postgres" />
   <property name="Password" value="12345678" />
   <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true" />
 </jdbc-connection-pool>

 <jdbc-resource jndi-name="jdbc_notebookusers_ds" pool-name="jdbc_notebookusers_pool" />
</resources>
```

and with the following command:

```
 asadmin add-resources glassfish-resources.xml
```

When I build the application with command `mvn -X package` I am getting the following bulk of the errors:

```
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc_notebookusers_ds' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc_notebookusers_ds not found]
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc_notebookusers_ds' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc_notebookusers_ds not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:429)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$ProviderContainerContractInfoImpl.lookupDataSource(JPADeployer.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc_notebookusers_ds not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:101)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
    ... 39 more
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc_notebookusers_ds' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc_notebookusers_ds not found]
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc_notebookusers_ds' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc_notebookusers_ds not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:429)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$ProviderContainerContractInfoImpl.lookupDataSource(JPADeployer.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc_notebookusers_ds not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:101)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
    ... 39 more
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl createEJBContainer
INFO: [EJBContainerProviderImpl] Cleaning up on failure ...
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService shutdown
INFO: JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup stop
INFO: Shutdown procedure finished
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM AppServerStartup run
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] exiting
Nov 18, 2012 12:22:34 AM org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl createEJBContainer
SEVERE: ejb.embedded.exception_instantiating
javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to deploy EJB modules - see log for details
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.255 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

My `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence                                       
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="javaee-db" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc_notebookusers_ds</jta-data-source>
    <class>beginning.javaee.notebook.User</class>
    <properties>
<!--       <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="12345678"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/> -->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>beginning.javaee.notebook</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-ee-notebook</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>simple-ee-notebook</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>            

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>beginning.javaee.notebook.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```